# Reading BigQuery in Golang. Not all expected results are given. What to do?

Tags: go, google-bigquery

Given that the SQL is running perfectly in Query Editor. Still after assigning it to a struct, the data seems to have different values. Why is it like that?

```
var RunQuery = func(req *http.Request, query string)(*bigquery.RowIterator, error){
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
    ctxWithDeadline, _ := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 30*time.Minute)
    bqClient, bqErr := bigquery.NewClient(ctxWithDeadline, project, option.WithCredentialsFile(serviceAccount))
    if bqErr != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "%v", bqErr)
        return nil, bqErr
    }
    q := bqClient.Query(query)
    job, err := q.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "%v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "%v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := status.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "%v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    it, err := job.Read(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "%v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Infof(ctx, "Total Rows: %v", it.TotalRows)
    return it, nil
}

type Customers struct {
    CustomerName string `bigquery:"customer_name"`
    CustomerAge  int    `bigquery:"customer_age"`
}


var rowsRead int

func main() {
   query := `SELECT 
                   name as customer_name,
                   age as customer_age
             FROM customer_table
             WHERE customerStatus = '0'`
   customerInformation, customerInfoErr := RunQuery(req, query, false)
   if customerInfoErr != nil {
       log.Errorf(ctx, "Fetching customer information error :: %v", customerInfoErr)
       return
   }
   for {
        var row Customers 
        err := customerInformation.Next(&row)
        log.Infof(ctx, "row %v", row)
        if err == iterator.Done {
             log.Infof(ctx, "ITERATION COMPLETE. Rows read %v", rowsRead)
             break
        }
        rowsRead++
   }
}
```

Let's say i have Query Results of 

`customer_name|customer_age
     cat     |    2
     dog     |    3
     horse   |    10`

But after assigning it to a struct the results was

`customer_name|customer_age
     ""      |    2
     dog     |    ""
     ""      |    ""`

Why is it like this? i even tested it on chunk where i set the limit to 1000, still the same results. But the query results in Query Editor is what i expect

Comment: if it's your real reqeust, you wrote `age as cutomer_age` so I think it can't give you the `customer_age` no ?

Comment: No. updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using `Value Loader` `bigquery.Value`. Instead of using expected struct in mapping the query results. used `map[string]bigquery.Value`. Still don't know why mapping query results with expected struct is not working perfectly. Here is my solution.

```
for {
        row := make(map[string]bigquery.Value)
        err := customerInformation.Next(&row)
        log.Infof(ctx, "row %v", row)
        if err == iterator.Done {
             log.Infof(ctx, "ITERATION COMPLETE. Rows read %v", rowsRead)
             break
        }
        rowsRead++
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If dst is a pointer to a struct, each column in the schema will be matched with an exported field of the struct that has the same name, ignoring the case. Unmatched schema columns and struct fields will be ignored.

[cloud.google.com/go/bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/go/bigquery)

Here you try to resolve customer_age to a struct property named CustomerAge. If you update it to Customer_Age or customer_age it should work.